Feign client http connection issue
I use feign client to connect to the downstream systems. Recently downstream systems had an outage but surprisingly all calls from our system to downstream system started timing out once downstream system is up and running. None of the calls reached downstream system but they are rather timed out in our system.
Here is the feign config:
feign:
  httpclient:
    max-connections: 300
    max-connections-per-route: 200
    follow-redirects: true

  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 5000
        readTimeout: 5000
      Client1:
        readTimeout: 1200000
      Client2:
        readTimeout: 1200000

